# Why is this regex experiencing catastrophic backtracking?

Tags: python, regex, performance

I've read [the articles](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) and [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218594/how-can-i-make-this-regular-expression-not-result-in-catastrophic-backtracking) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29751230/regex-pattern-catastrophic-backtracking) on catastrophic backtracking in regular expressions and how it can be caused by nested `+` and `*` quantifiers. However, my regexes are still encountering catastrophic backtracking *without* nested quantifiers. Can someone help me understand why?

I wrote these regexes to search for [a specific type of rhyme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cynghanedd#Cynghanedd_groes_.28.22cross-harmony.22.29) in lines of welsh poetry. The rhyme consists of all the consonants in the beginning of the line being repeated at the end, and there must be a space between the beginning and end consonants. I've already removed all the vowels, but there are two exceptions that make these regexes ugly. First, there are allowed to be consonants in the middle that don't repeat, and if there are any, it's a different type of rhyme. Second, the letters m, n, r, h, and v are allowed to interrupt the rhyme (appear in the beginning but not in the end or vice versa), but they can't be ignored because sometimes the rhyme consists only of those letters.

My script automatically builds a regex for each line and tests it. It works the rest of the time, but this one line is giving catastrophic backtracking. The line's text without vowels is:

```
nn  Frvvn  Frv v
```

The regex automatically finds that `nn Frvvn` rhymes with `Frv v`, so then it tries it again with the last letter (the `n` in `Frvvn`) required in the back. If it's not required, then the rhyme can be shortened. Here's the regex:

```
^(?P<s_letters>         # starting letters
[mnrhv]*?\s*n{0,2}      # any number of optional letters or any number
                        # of spaces can come between rhyming letters
[mnrhv]*?\s*n{0,2}
[mnrhv]*?\s*F{1,2}
[mnrhv]*?\s*[rR]?(?:\s*[rR])? # r can also rhyme with R, but that's
                              # not relevant here (I think)
[mnrhv]*?\s*v{0,2}
[mnrhv]*?\s*v{0,2}
[mnrhv]*?\s*n{1,2}
[mnrhv\s]*?)
(?P<m_letters>          # middle letters
[^\s]*?(?P<caesura>\s)  # the caesura (end of the rhyme) is the
                        # first space after the rhyme     
.*)                     # End letters come as late as possible
(?P<e_letters>          # End group
[mnrhv]*?\s*n{0,2}
[mnrhv]*?\s*n{0,2}
[mnrhv]*?\s*F{1,2}
[mnrhv]*?\s*[rR]?(?:\s*[rR])?
[mnrhv]*?\s*v{0,2}
[mnrhv]*?\s*v{0,2}
[mnrhv]*?\s*n{1,2}
[mnrhv\s]*?)$
```

Even though it doesn't have any nested quantifiers, it still takes forever to run. Regexes for other lines that were generated in the same way run quickly. Why is this?

Comment: Waayyy to many optional stuff that all overlap. You should be able to pare this down to a few lines.

Comment: There is a general rule using regex. Any compound sub-expression that is optional should contain something that is non-optional. This helps the engine align on these constants. They are called pseudo-anchors. The best approach is to contain the options within a cluster group and separate them from each other with alternations. Try to isolate the different forms and follow each one to a match. Avoid impulsive injection of optional simple constructs in series with each other.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not seeing any nested quantifiers, but I am seeing a lot of ambiguities that would cause high-exponent polynomial runtime. For example, consider this part of the regex:

```
[mnrhv]*?\s*[rR]?(?:\s*[rR])? # r can also rhyme with R, but that's
                              # not relevant here (I think)
[mnrhv]*?\s*v{0,2}
[mnrhv]*?\s*v{0,2}
[mnrhv]*?\s*n{1,2}
[mnrhv\s]*?)
(?P<m_letters>          # middle letters
[^\s]*?(?P<caesura>\s)  # the caesura (end of the rhyme) is the
```

Suppose the regex engine is at this point, and the text it's seeing is just a huge block of `n`s. Those `n`s can be divided between the following parts of the regex:

```
[mnrhv]*?\s*[rR]?(?:\s*[rR])?
^^^^^^^^^

[mnrhv]*?\s*v{0,2}
^^^^^^^^^

[mnrhv]*?\s*v{0,2}
^^^^^^^^^
[mnrhv]*?\s*n{1,2}
^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^
[mnrhv\s]*?)
^^^^^^^^^^^
(?P<m_letters>
[^\s]*?(?P<caesura>\s)
^^^^^^^
```

If the number of `n`s is `N`, then there are `O(N**6)` ways to divide the `n`s, since there are 6 `*?` blocks that match `n` here, and everything in between is optional or also matches `n`.

Are those `\s` parts mandatory? If so, you might be able to improve runtime by putting a `+` instead of a `*` on them.